# dynamodb won't run locally

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Following [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html), I downloaded dynamodb.jar, and ran the following command:

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

It seems to work:

[image: console output]

But whe I type `http://localhost:8000`, I get an error:

[image: error]

What is wrong?

Comment: fixed grammar and spelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL should be http://localhost:8000/shell. Please use this link. It should work.